# Java decompiler vs java disassembler

Tags: java

I am preparing core java and i got following doubt

**javap** is dis-assembler or de-compiler? what is the difference between them? which java CLI commands are used ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java a Compiled or an interpreted programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326071/is-java-a-compiled-or-an-interpreted-programming-language)

Comment: @sphanley not the same thing, the question you mention is whether Java is interpreted or compiled, here the question is about the utility javap

Comment: Side note: Oracle states [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) that "The **javap** command disassembles one or more class files." I'm not sure if they're following "technical" terminology, but it at least seems to match morgano's answer.

Comment: The `javap` command disassembles one or more class files and shows the byte code information.
where as, Decompiling is something which converts these byte codes into java source code.

Comment: @morgano fair enough, I'm not familiar with javap so I assumed that it was a typo and this was just someone asking in poor english whether Java would be disassemlbled or decompiled.

Answer (score 9):

Javap is just an "informal" dis-assembler, its output gives you information about the bytecode, but is not suitable for it to be used by an "assembler", it is rather for it to be read by a human.

The traditional difference (from the C language world):

- Compiler: compiles a relatively high-level source code to assembly language
- Assembler: compiles assembly code to machine code

take your conclusions for "de-compiler" and "dis-assembler"

Sometimes a software that does both steps (disassemble and decompile) is also called a decompiler, but it still depends on the context