# Python multithreading takes longer to execute the multiple jar files

Tags: java, python, multithreading, memory, time

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor and giving exact same tasks to workers. The task is to run a jar file and do something with it. the problem I am facing is related to timings.

**Case 1:** I submit one task to the pool and the worker completes in 8 seconds.

**Case 2:** I submit same task twice into the pool, and both workers completes around ~10.50 seconds.

**Case 3:** I submit same task thrice into the pool, and all three workers completes around ~13.38 seconds.

**Case 4:** I submit same task 4 times into the pool, and all fore workers completes around ~18.88 seconds.

If I replace the workers tasks to `time.sleep(8)` (instead of running jar file), then all 4 workers finish at ~8 seconds. Is this because of the fact that, the OS before executing java code has to create java environment first, which the OS is not able to manage it in parallel ?

Can someone explain me why is the execution time increasing for same task, while running in parallel ?Thanks :)

Here is how I am executing the pool;

```
   def transfer_files(file_name):
        raw_file_obj = s3.Object(bucket_name='foo-bucket', key=raw_file_name)
        body = raw_file_obj.get()['Body']

        # prepare java command
        java_cmd = "java -server -ms650M -mx800M -cp {} commandline.CSVExport --sourcenode=true --event={} --mode=human_readable --configdir={}" \
        .format(jar_file_path, event_name, config_dir)

        # Run decoder_tool by piping in the encoded binary bytes
        log.info("Running java decoder tool for file {}".format(file_name))
        res = run([java_cmd], cwd=tmp_file_path, shell=True, input=body.read(), stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
        res_output = res.stderr.decode("utf-8")

        if res.returncode != 0:
            if 'Unknown event' in res_output:
                log.error("Exception occurred whilst running decoder tool")
                raise Exception("Unknown event {}".format(event_name))
        log.info("decoder tool output: \n" + res_output)

    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS) as pool:
            # add new task(s) into thread pool
            pool.map(transfer_file, ['fileA_for_workerA', 'fileB_for_workerB'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using multithreading doesn't necessarily mean it will execute faster. You would have to deal with the GIL for Python to execute the commands. Think of it like 1 person can do 1 task faster than 1 person doing 2 tasks at the same time. He/she would have to multitask and do part of thread 1 first, than switch to thread 2, etc. The more threads, the more things the python interpreter has to do.

The same thing might be happening for Java too. I don't use Java but they might have the same problems. Here, [Is Java a Compiled or an Interpreted programming language ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326071/is-java-a-compiled-or-an-interpreted-programming-language) it says that the JVM converts Java on the fly, so the JVM would probably have to deal with the same problems as Python.

And, for the `time.sleep(8)`, what it does is just use up processor time for the thread, so it would be easy to switch between a bunch of waiting tasks.